# Ubuntu 16.04 - New install shows strange failed message

Tags: boot, 16.04, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

Just Installed Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Win 10, install completed ok. Then went to reboot and got this message so thought I would type it up here in case it is relevant to any troubles I'm about to have with the new install...

```
[   0.565895] platform MSFT0101:00: failed to claim resource 0 (next line...) 
[   0.565906] acpi MSFT0101:00: platform device creation failed: -16  (next line...) 
[ *** ]A start job is running for Ubuntu live CD installer (1min 23s / no limit)
```

Well it's been longer than 1.23 so forced a reboot. The computer boots straight into Windows. I tried several reinstalls with different Ubuntu versions but it doesn't work. I think it is something to do with not being able to get the boot `grub` to install - have already tried everything I could find on my other installs with no luck.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: In the same boat tonight. Did you get past it?

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/834523/cannot-install-xubuntu-16-04-1

Answer (score 1):

With the LiveCD install boot-repair (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and run it. Or you can try chrooting into the installed system and installing GRUB manually, there's a good amount of info about that on the internet.

Comment: I've been getting by, by using F9 on boot up, then selecting which boot I want (Ubuntu or Windows is offered). It's ok as long as I don't forget to hit F9 - otherwise the HP software starts doing a self repair. One time I let it get too far and had to do something (maybe that boot repair) but normally it's ok like this.