# Cannot install Xubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, xubuntu

I downloaded the ISO file and burned it on a DVD. When I boot my PC to the DVD and then select `Install Xubuntu` i get to a point where it says:

> `A start job is running for Ubuntu Live CD installer (Xmin Xs /no limit)`.

At this point the counter just goes on but nothing else happens anymore. (I also tried installing Linux Mint and Ubuntu on my PC and both also failed before even showing the installer)

Comment: Have you tried installing Ubuntu using a USB is might be a easier method and in most cases works the best. There could be a number of issues going on here not knowing what the specs are for your machine

Comment: Have you tried "ctrl + alt + f1". Doing this fixed things for me when trying to boot the Live CD and it hanged in the way you describe it.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue just 1 hour ago. I've just disconnected LAN wire and everything went OK.
IMPORTANT: It was an old notebook and wifi also didn't work during installation, in your case you might have to disable it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

there might be different possible reasons for that, Can you download it again from http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ and try to install it with USB. It will be easy to install with USB Drive.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue with a LiveCD from a USB drive...

Comment: I don't see a possibility to download Xubuntu from the given link.